# How to force single word spacing (Ideally in Excel, maybe Notepad++ ?)

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++

Please rest assured I have spent a week searching for an answer to my question without success.

I have a Excel spreadsheet which randomly generates a string of words in each cell from a word list.  The problem is, I need there to only be a single word spacing between each cell when I copy and paste from the spreadsheet.  I have spent the week trying to force Excel to do this without success, any ideas?

If not, hopefully if I paste into Notepad++, there is a way to highlight the pasted data then force it to only have a single space between each word?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the code that creates the string.

Comment: =INDEX($A:$A,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA($A:$A)),1)

Comment: @JMan you mean like =TRIM(...) which removes every space before and after a word, but non that are in between words?

Comment: Afraid not, I mean literally copying and pasting data out of a series of single cells which contain a single word, then when you paste them, it only having a single space between each word copied from a cell.

Comment: Can you give a small example with bogus data?

Comment: IF you have Office 365 Excel; `=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,B:B)`

Comment: It keeps auto correctly and removes all spacing!  I might just use superuser.com hahahaha!

Comment: Put the string between ``

Comment: Apologies Scott, I have very poor knowledge of Excel.. could you please post an example?

Comment: no, on this site to show how the spaces are wrong you need to wrap the string in `` to force it to show as code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove multiple spaces between words, then try this short macro:

```
Sub SingleWordSpacing()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(2)
        If InStr(1, r.Text, " ") > 0 Then
            With Application.WorksheetFunction
                r.Value = .Trim(r.Text)
            End With
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I think this is for multiple words within cells?  This project has single words within each cell which I need to copy and paste out of Excel, so need to have the pasted data to only have a single space between words?